# How to add Chinese Input Method to English Android 2.2 Phone

Tags: localization, input-methods, htc-legend

I have an HTC Legend with Android 2.2. I can switch between the standard input method (on-screen qwerty) and Graffiti by a long press in an input field.

I would like to be able to type chinese characters (for a dictionary app etc) without using pinyin. For example using wubi, ckc or some similar method.

Is it possible to add a new input method of this sort or to enable it if already built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of alternative keyboards available on the playstore, which register as separate IMEs. One example I found is [LIME HD Chinese IME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.toload.main.hd)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c2Pm.jpg)</sup>, another one [Cantonese keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milesleung.android.softKeyboard.cantoneseKeyboard)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usuOc.png)</sup>:

[image: LIME] [image: Cantonese keyboard]

There are several more available (the developer of the second keyboard offers some other variants as well), many are linked on these apps' playstore pages.